# What is the equivalent Lightning method sendCTIMessage() to make an outbound call?

Tags: lightning, opencti, twilio

sendCTIMessage() is working flawlessly in Classic and VF page.

From below below code snippet `sendCTIMessage('/CLICK_TO_DIAL?DN=XXXXXXXXXX');` is talking to my Twilio Flex configuration set in Call Center set up and making a call to XXXXXXXXXX as expected in classic.

```
 <apex:page standardController="Lead">

     <script type="text/javascript">
        function makeACall(){
         console.log('sendCTIMessage: '+sendCTIMessage);
          sendCTIMessage('/CLICK_TO_DIAL?DN=XXXXXXXXXX');
        }
     </script>
    <input type="button" name="call" value="call" onClick="makeACall();"/>
</apex:page>
```

But when I use this in Lighting it says sendCTIMessage is undefined in console inspect.

**My requirement is**: Will have a quick Action button on the lightning lead/contact page. When the user clicks the button it will make a server call to get other Lead/Contact details along with the Phone Number and make a call to that number then navigates to that Lead/Contact. We are using Twilio Flex as a vendor.

Anyone has any idea how to make `sendCTIMessage()` works in Lightning experience or is there any other way I can make outbound calls in lightning.

Thank you!
Charan

Comment: Have you tried if any method from [Open CTI Developer Guide: Methods for Lightning Experience](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_methods_intro_lightning.htm) work?

Comment: @PrzemysławTamoń Yeah. But all those methods are to perform some actions when the user clicks on some Phone number. Basically to play around DOM or UI etc. But I wanted to implement something like sendCTIMessage('/CLICK_TO_DIAL?DN) in lightning with some params so that salesforce will look around call center settings and talk to URL which is mentioned in call center settings. So I would like to have lightning:clickToDial / lightning-click-to-dial behind the scene functionality in my Lighting component.